# Highlight environment by setting a gray background color

Tags: color, highlighting, backgrounds

The title explains everything. I have a theorem with `ntheorem` and want to highlight it with a gray background color. What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: The `ntheorem` manual has examples that describe this. google: ntheorem.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `mdframed` package. Here is an example from the document with a little modification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newtheorem{mdtheorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{theorem}%
  {\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray]\begin{mdtheorem}}%
  {\end{mdtheorem}\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
test
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems that TeX Live lacks exactly this package. Any other solution?

Comment: I'm sure that TeX Live 2011 have [this package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed). But your TeX dist may be too old.

Comment: For now, I trust you that it works - furthermore i have changed the highlighting box to `\theorem(pre|post)work{(\bigskip\hrule|\hrule\bigskip)}` and it's good enough. Hope you understand my notation :D

Comment: You can either install the [`mdframed` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) manually, or update your TeX Live distribution. According to a quick compilation of @Leo's code on [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com) - which runs pdftex from TeX Live 2009 - it compiles without problem.

Comment: This solution works great even with TeX Live 2010.

Comment: @Christian: I understand your temporary solution well, although it is not very well. :)

Comment: @Leo Liu: It will do it for now! Nonetheless, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses `ntheorem`s built-in shaded theorems; note that this version requires `pstricks`, and hence you can not use `pdflatex`. It breaks across pages just fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[standard,framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}                             
\definecolor{silver}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremseparator{}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
      \psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=silver,linecolor=black]}
\newshadedtheorem{myshadedtheorem}{Definition}


\begin{document}

\begin{myshadedtheorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{myshadedtheorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution without `mdframed` package. It is NOT as good as the `mdframed` solution. The whole `theorem` environment is put in a box, thus it cannot be break between pages. You may need to put it in a float.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newsavebox\thmbox
\newtheorem{mytheorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{theorem}%
  {\begin{lrbox}{\thmbox}%
   \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}
   \begin{mytheorem}}%
  {\end{mytheorem}%
   \end{minipage}%
   \end{lrbox}%
   \begin{trivlist}
     \item[]\colorbox{lightgray}{\usebox\thmbox}
   \end{trivlist}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
test
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: Don't use it if you can access `mdframed` package. I made it CW and I don't need any score from this.