# Highlight theorem environment using todonotes

Tags: boxes, highlighting, amsthm, todonotes

I'm trying to highlight theorem-like environment (defined using `amsthm`) utilizing `todonotes`.

In the preamble I have:

```
\newtheorem{que}{Question}
\newcommand*{\question}[1]{%
  \todo[inline,color=red!10,caption={}]{\begin{que}
      #1
    \end{que}
  }}
```

Problem is, that in the body, when having something like:

```
\question{\lipsum[10]}
```

It yields:
[image]

I tried to define a `theoremstyle` as follows:

```
\newtheoremstyle{queSty}%
{-1em} % Space above
{0pt} % Space below
{} % body font
{} % Indent amount
{} % Theorem head font
{:} % Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em} % Space after theorem head
{} % Theorem head spec
```

Using this style yielded the following box:
[image]
This is better, but still not good enough. Setting the first argument to `40pt` for instance does increases this vertical spacing, but I cannot make it go away.

**How can I get rid of the empty line at the beginning of the box? I want to have the same spacing as the one at the bottom.**

I guess I could tweak the solution provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24828/412) for example, but I want to try and use `todonotes`.

Comment: You can try something like `\begin{que}\vspace*{-1.5em}#1\end{que}` but you need to determine the exact dimension "1.5 em ??" or perhaps someone knows the dimension used  in "newtheorem". The problem comes from `newtheorem`and not from `todonotes`. It's necessary to give us a complete example.

Comment: @AlainMatthes: I agree, and it seems like the problem is indeed coming from `amsthm` and `newtheorem`. I don't see what further details are needed. I'm using `newtheorem` out of the box of `amsthm`.

Comment: It's preferable to give a complete example (MWE) to see if you get interactions from other packages. Your problem is simple, `\newtheorem`  places extra space before the first line. With amsthm and a style, you can't reduce enough the extra space. I see two possibilities : you can perhaps create a personal environment, or you can study exactly the command `\newtheorem` to know what space is added before the first line. Another possibility is perhaps to hack `\newtheorem`.

Comment: I'm not sure `todonotes` is the right tool; have a look at `mdframed`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As egreg has said, `todonotes` is really the wrong tool for this job. You can get exactly the same result if you use the `mdframed` package, and the line spacing all just works out perfectly when you do. Here is a 'before' and 'after' comparison for you -- first using `todonotes` and second using `mdframed`.

[image]

And here is the code for generating that.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\newtheorem{que}{Question}
\newcommand*{\question}[1]{\todo[inline,color=red!10,caption={}]{\begin{que}#1\end{que}}}

\newmdtheoremenv[%
backgroundcolor=red!10,%
outerlinecolor=black,%
innertopmargin = \topskip,%
splittopskip = \topskip,%
ntheorem = true,%
skipabove = \baselineskip,%
skipbelow = \baselineskip,%
roundcorner=4]
{Que}{Question}

\lipsum[2]

\question{\lipsum[2]}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{Que}
\lipsum[2]
\end{Que}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using **tcolorbox** is given at this thread (answer nb 32): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/204888

It worked for me, contrary to **mdframed** (because on some previous definitions in my file).

Comment: The `32` on that answer is not the answer number, but (essentially) the number of up votes the answer has received, so is very likely to change.  If you have a solution using `tcolorbox` instead, it would be better to post it here adapted to the question at hand, rather linking to something in a different context.